# Create a Batch file to back up the folders and within that how to exclude one of the folder for back up

Tags: batch-file

I have created a Batch File that will back up all the folders and its subfolders using XCopy. Below is the code: I already have a script that gets the current date and time. I am setting it to curr_date and curr_time.

```
@echo off

Xcopy /S /I /E /H D:\WorkingTFS\TEST_COP D:\BackUp\%curr_date%_%curr_time%_backup 
pause
```

Now it is backing up all the folders correctly. Now I want to exclude one of the folder (For example: OldTest folder that exists in D:\WorkingTFS\TEST_COP) while creating backup. Can anyone help me in doing this

Answer (score 0):

why not just use EXCLUDE parameter?

```
@echo off
echo WorkingTFS\TEST_COP\OldTest >exclude.txt
Xcopy /S /I /E /H D:\WorkingTFS\TEST_COP D:\BackUp\%curr_date%_%curr_time%_backup /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt
pause
```